# Calling Fragment's method from host Activity

Tags: android, methods, nullpointerexception

I've got a host Activity and a Fragment. In this fragment I have an update method that loads some data in an AsyncTask from the DB and updates a GridView.

When I call this method from the host activity sometimes I get an NullPointerExeption and I don't know why...

Here is the Activity's method which is an interface:

```
@Override
public void onDataSetChange() {

    ((CalendarFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(Constants.FRAGMENT_CALENDAR_TAG)).updateGridView();
}
```

And the Fragment's update method:

```
public void updateGridView() {

    // Loading the new updated data
    mLoadingTask = new LoadingDataTask();
    mLoadingTask.execute((Void) null);
}
```

Here is the exception in the logcat:

> 04-17 12:05:28.366: E/AndroidRuntime(17789): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-17 12:05:28.366: E/AndroidRuntime(17789): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   04-17 12:05:28.366: E/AndroidRuntime(17789):    at com.sk.neverforget.MainActivity.onDataSetChange(MainActivity.java:397)
>   04-17 12:05:28.366: E/AndroidRuntime(17789):    at com.sk.neverforget.fragments.DiaryFragment$StoringDataTask.onPostExecute(DiaryFragment.java:543)
>   04-17 12:05:28.366: E/AndroidRuntime(17789):    at com.sk.neverforget.fragments.DiaryFragment$StoringDataTask.onPostExecute(DiaryFragment.java:1)
>   04-17 12:05:28.366: E/AndroidRuntime(17789):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
>   04-17 12:05:28.366: E/AndroidRuntime(17789):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
>   04-17 12:05:28.366: E/AndroidRuntime(17789):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
>   04-17 12:05:28.366: E/AndroidRuntime(17789):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   04-17 12:05:28.366: E/AndroidRuntime(17789):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   04-17 12:05:28.366: E/AndroidRuntime(17789):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
>   04-17 12:05:28.366: E/AndroidRuntime(17789):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   04-17 12:05:28.366: E/AndroidRuntime(17789):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   04-17 12:05:28.366: E/AndroidRuntime(17789):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   04-17 12:05:28.366: E/AndroidRuntime(17789):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>   04-17 12:05:28.366: E/AndroidRuntime(17789):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: my guess is that the findfragmentbytag returns null, try asigning your fragment to a variable before running the method and debug to see if your fragment is null or not, if so figure out why it's null.

Comment: Strange. This tags are located and set in a separate static class called Constants. But I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Post the logcat of the exception please.

Comment: Updated the thread with the logcat message.

Comment: What I mean to say is that perhaps the fragment is not found and thus null is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Before you call updateGridView, it is recommended to check your CalendarFragment for null. It is not clear when you add this fragment. It is possible that it is not added yet, or already removed.

```
@Override
public void onDataSetChange() {

CalendarFragment fragment =  ((CalendarFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(Constants.FRAGMENT_CALENDAR_TAG));
if(fragment != null) fragment.updateGridView();
}
```

Comment: This is a good point but I don't think that it's the case here. Simply because I have an activity host which is starting a fragment. From this fragment I'm starting another one in which I do some work and save it in the local database. In the way back, e.g. popping out the last fragment I go back to the previous one in the stack, e.g. the first fragment I'm starting from the activity host. :)

Comment: It will be interesting if you add "FragmentManager.enableDebugLogging(enabled)" in your code, and public logs.

Comment: Just enabled it (didn't know such "thing" existed! :) ) and everything is fine from what I can see from the logs. :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is not to get the fragment from the fragment manager by tag but to use the local variable that holds the fragment and from there to call the method.

Comment: I think I am having the same issue as you. When you say that you got your code to work by accessing the fragment from the "local variable", what do you mean? Can you post your code for accessing a fragment and its method from the fragment's local variable? Thanks!